# Can't run the docker

Tags: linux, docker

I just install the Docker on Ubuntu18.04 by using:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

`sudo apt install docker.io`

`sudo service docker start`

All of the above commands work normally, but when I check the status of the docker service`sudo service docker status`, it shows"Docker is not running". I have tried `sudo service docker restart`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You'd better stick to the installation process proposed by Docker here: [docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the `docker-ce` package:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

for more information check the documentation at: [install docker ce](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce)

Comment: I have tried to turn to install the docker-ce, but it doesn't work either. By the way, docker-ce is just a different version of docker.io.

Comment: HAve you tried executing a docker `sudo docker run hello-world`?

Comment: or ask docker directly what the status is with `sudo docker info`